# Azure VM CPU utlilization metrics (no data)

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I am running several VM's in Azure. Size DS14 and my cpu metrics look like this. "No Available Data" What am I missing? How can I get it to show the CPU utilization of the box?

[image]

Comment: What did Azure support say?

Comment: I didnt ask Azure support, as they require a support contract...which I don't have. This is why I am asking here first.

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote. This seems to be a perfectly reasonable question to me...

Comment: I think the vm agent is not working properly. Try reinstalling. Had a similar problem a few months back

Comment: @BrunoFaria how do I do that?

Comment: I see docs all over for updating the VM after installing the Agent, but none seem to work for me. (I am using ResourceManager)

Comment: I don't understand why this is closed. It is so hard to find up-to-date azure documentation anywhere. I ask a question here, and it gets closed. What more information do you need? I don't have any more info.

Comment: @ChrisKooken I have to agree - the moderators seem to have been overzealous in closing this topic.

Comment: same for me. shame on the person who voted you down. we pay for this as part of azure and it's disgraceful that we can't log a ticket

Answer (score 3):

As Bruno Faria responded earlier, this sounds to me also like the VM Agent is not working properly.

Here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/vm-agent-and-extensions-part-2/ are some information on how you can check if the agent is installed properly in a VM and how to install it, if needed.

Comment: I am using ResourceManager instead of classic. $x.VM.ProvisionGuestAgent doesn't exist in resourceManager

Answer (score 0):

I think you can enable vm diagnostic first, then choose any fields you want to monitor. Some of the information can be displayed on the screen immediately.

Comment: Enable basic metrics, and select the data that you want to monitor, then refresh the portal for a few times.

Comment: It has been enabled for about 12 hours, and still no luck. I have updated my screenshots.